# How do I make a program I've previously opened have a cold run when my laptop has Intel Optane turned on?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, debug, optane

The first time I open a program on windows it is slow to load then if I close it and open it again, it's fast to load. This suggests that windows is caching the frequently and recently used programs in advance to make it faster to load and run. The first run is called a cold run and the second run is called a warm run.

How can I disable a specific program from opening in a warm run?

I am trying to reproduce a bug on a program so it can be fixed, but if the memory for this program is going to be cached in advanced based on predictions, then the bug will be hard to reproduce, as the bug tends to be about memory usage and allocation.

My laptop has Intel Optane which caches programs in the memory in advance based on predictions based on frequent and recent usage, to speed up the computer. How can I disable this for a **specific** program?

Comment: so are you worried about the application binaries, process stack, or external data being cached? I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to control the cache by exe (I'm going to guess Optane doesn't rely on the OS for much instruction on how it does its thing). There may be a utility out there that will give you the control to clean up  selected contents of the cache, or even force it to globally regenerate, but I'd also guess that optane is only caching binaries and external data. the program stack should form again at execute. can you confirm that 2nd run has impact on private working set?

Comment: What does your question mean? What am I supposed to do? What is enabling the `memory (private working set)` column in task manager under the `details` tab going to do? The number will either be higher or lower than it was before. All it will show is a number.

Comment: right but is that number the same on cold start as warm? or is the warm start value the same as the cold start after its run for a minute or two? you are concerned about the way the program handles memory (de)allocation, so the memory you are concerned about is part of the processes virtual memory address-space. that memory will be allocated when the process begins, so Cache comes into play when loading recently grabbed data into that address-space. if its in the cache its much faster, but the cache is just for IO data. if the values are more or less the same, optane won't hurt your testing.

Comment: I'm not the one programming software, I'm trying to reproduce a bug so I can get the software developers to fix it.

Comment: Are you referring to the prefetch cache?  Google "windows prefetch cache" to find out where the file lives and how to delete it.  I have never had a problem with it but I am a programmer and have had to delete these files for performance testing in the past.

Comment: Windows has cached DLL's, libraries uses by applications, for a long while. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4ba13d3-b2ef-4fb5-a2d9-074a825da82c/how-to-flushclearh-the-system-dll-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [Intel Optane Memory and Storage Management](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/intel-optane-memory-and-storage-management/9mzng5hzwz1t?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) program in the Microsoft Store. After installing it I opened it and found that my laptop isn't compatible with it.

[image: intel optane enable or disable, intel optane memory and storage management]

However I know of a windows feature that caches programs and files you're predicted to use in the future to speed your computer making it faster. It's called Superfetch, that in Windows 10 it's been renamed SysMain. Even so, it's still colloquially referred to as Superfetch in 2021.

To enable or disable it, open task manager, the services window, or computer management. Task manager has less features for managing services.

- Windows + X then click Task Manager, or right click the taskbar then
  click task manager, or use Ctrl + Alt + Del to open it
- You could open Computer Managment (from start menu or Windows Key + X)
- Entering services.msc on the run window (that appears with Windows Key + R)
- Search for Services on the Start Menu

Once open you should see a window that looks like this.

[image: sysmain superfetch service on task manager]

[image: sysmain superfetch on computer management]

From Task Manager you can right click a service then stop it, but it will be enabled after a restart.

To make sure it stays disabled (or off) after restarting your computer, you'll have to use the services window. Right click the service, click properties, then change the startup type in the general tab from "automatic" to "disabled". Don't forget to turn it back to automatic when you've finished what you aimed to do. Also you can click the stop button to stop the service.

Click OK or Apply to save your settings.

So it turns out that I didn't need to disable Intel Optane as my computer never had it in the first place, it was Superfetch that needed disabling. There's more information on Superfetch in Windows 10 if you search Google or Bing.